# how to insert a new notes document in the domino server with c# and the usage of interop.domino.dll?

Tags: c#, .net, vbscript, lotus-notes

This is my first question here.

I want to know the syntax to insert a new  notes document in the lotus notes database if it is not existing using c#.
I have a code in vb script bit I do not know about vb script and lotus notes.

```
     set doc = vw.GetDocumentByKey(empno)

        if doc is nothing then
          set doc = db.CreateDocument
          doc.Form = "EmployeeRepository"
          doc.Employno = empno
          doc.FirstName = fname
          doc.LastName = lname
          doc.Group = grp
          doc.Department = dept
          doc.officeemailaddress = officemail
          doc.officegeneralline = officegenline
          doc.designation = desig
          doc.officeaddress = officeadd 
        else
          doc.FirstName = fname
          doc.LastName = lname
          doc.Group = grp
          doc.Department = dept
          doc.officeemailaddress = officemail
          doc.officegeneralline = officegenline
          doc.designation = desig
          doc.officeaddress = officeadd     
        end if

        call doc.save(true, true)
```

How can I achieve this in c#?

Comment: Is it necessary to do it in C#? Java is a good option. The library Notes.jar is part of the IBM Notes installation...

Comment: @Mario This is a part in my windows service which is written in c# so it is better to do with c#. I used ReplaceItemValue method and the problem was solved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The C# syntax for the if statement is different.  Instead of this:

```
if doc is nothing then
  ...
else
  ...
end if
```

You will need

```
if (doc != null)
{
  ...
}
else
{
  ...
}
```

Also, the C# language does not support shorthand notation doc.item = X.  So the assignments in that format in the above code need to be changed to use the ReplaceItemValue method.  I.e., instead of this:

```
  doc.Form = "EmployeeRepository"
  doc.Employno = empno
  doc.FirstName = fname
  doc.LastName = lname
```

you need to use this:

```
  doc.ReplaceItemValue("Form","EmployeeRepository");
  doc.ReplaceItemValue("Employno",empno);
  doc.ReplaceItemValue("FirstName", fname);
  doc.ReplaceItemValue("LastName", lname);
```

Answer (score 0):

I might also suggest trying an ExpandoObject (although I haven't tried that yet, but I'm about to give it a go).  It's a dynamic type so you have to be careful with how you create it, but you could keep adding additional properties to it without having to instantiate them directly:

```
    dynamic noteDocument = new System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject();

    noteDocument.ShortName = "wonkaWillie";
    noteDocument.Comment = "No Comment";
    noteDocument.MailSystem = "Other";
    noteDocument.PowerLevel = "It's over NINE THOUSAND!!!!!";
```

I suppose you could just as easily (and probably be a little tighter of a solution) to have a pre-formatted class ready for the occasion of adding data into a specific document format too though.

---

So the ExpandoObject method works, but using a class with explicitly declared fields / properties is much cleaner....you can pass in an instance of a class to a method that performs this pretty handily:

```
   class NotesDocumentItemClass
    {
         public string Form {get; set;} = "Person";
         public string FullName {get; set;} = "Over 9000/Notes/Address/Or/Whatever";
    }
```

---

and then  pass an instance of that class into a method like.....

```
    private bool AddEntry(NotesDatabase db, NoteDocumentItemClass d)
    {
            NotesDocument newDoc = db.CreateDocument();
            doc.ReplaceItemValue("Form", d.Person);
            doc.ReplaceItemValue("FullName", d.FullName);
            return newDoc.Save();

    }
```